# How would I go about adding a custom filter in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, haml

So I'm pretty new to Angular Js. I'm trying to accomplish a simple problem. I just need to truncate a string of text. I know there is the limitTo filter and I could just attach it to an element, but this needs to be dynamic.

[image: This is my HAML FILE]

[image: This is my angular file]

Here is also a link to the pen
codepen.io/Brushel/pen/QMXPWN?editors=1010

Comment: You should write your code into post and not insert images

Comment: @alexander.polomodov For some reason, it was formatting the HAML really weird. Thank you though, _I will remember that for future posts_

Comment: @ThomasBrushel What are you trying to acomplish with the custom filter?

Comment: what needs to be dynamic?the filter limit?it is already dynamic

Comment: @NarenMurali Basically what I'm trying to do is create a truncate directive that truncates text after a certain number of characters are achieved. this directive should be able to have the number of characters or width passed into it to then add in the truncation and should show some kind of link to expand it or a link to a page to show the full detail. There should also be an option to not show a link and make it so that it just shows an elipsses. This would be important for the avatar where the username may get too long we may need to cut it off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example implementing all the requirements, use this template to build your directive.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

```
app.directive('truncate', function() {
  function link(scope, element, attrs){
    console.log(scope.input)
    console.log(scope.maxCharacters)
  }

  return{
    restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
      input: '=',
      maxCharacters: '=',
      href: '=',
      isShowMore: '='
      },
    template: '<h1 ng-init="limit=true;length=maxCharacters">{{input | limitTo: length}}<a ng-attr-href="{{ href ? \'#\': undefined }}" ng-click="limit=!limit;length=limit?maxCharacters: \'\'">{{isShowMore?"Show More":"..."}}</a></h1>',
    link: link
  }

});
```